# Easiest method/library to draw directed graphs (out to a .jpg file) in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, graph

I have a list of nodes and edges in my program, and I want to draw them out to a .jpg or .png file as a graph.  The nodes have names that I'd like to be displayed as well, on the nodes.

What is the simplest way of doing this, likely by a library of some sort?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'simplest' is highly subjective. [Boost Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/libs/graph/doc/index.html) has a bidirectional interface to [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), that surely can be used very easily, but, if you are willing to study the interface, can do very sophisticated layouts.